# Errors trying to run a python script from a batch file

Tags: python, batch-file

I have this line in my bat file:

C:\Python26\python.exe C:\myPythonDirectory.py

But it fails giving the error: can't open file [Errno2] no such file or directory.

Could it be giving an error because there is a space in one of the folder names in my python directory?

Comment: `myPythonDirectory.py` is a strange name for a module!

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.  If there's a space in the path, you need to put the whole path in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If there are spaces in the names of the directories you need to use the below code. For example, the name of the directory and the path is "D:\My New Bot\main.py" .  as there is a gap between the words , python recognises only the first word and tries to find path as "D:\My" which does not exist. Please use the below code :

path = r"D:\My New Bot\main.py"

This will work.

Comment: This does not really answer the question, which was about calling the script in a batch file. Your syntax would be for creating a `path` variable inside the Python script with a file name that has spaces, on Windows.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32090077)